# MKpolyline not displaying correctly for given coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, polyline

Im trying to draw MKpolyline using following code.

```
var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

let locationDetails = myArray as! [Location]

for each in locationDetails{
    print("Latitude \(each.latitude) - Longitude \(each.longitude)")
    points.append(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(each.latitude, each.longitude))
}

let centerLocation : Location = myArray.anyObject() as! Location
let centerPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(centerLocation.latitude, centerLocation.longitude);

print("POINTS \(points)")

let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: points, count: points.count)
mapView.add(polyline)

let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerPoint, 5000.0, 7000.0)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

but im getting messy polyline. see attached Screenshot. first i thought problem with coordinates. but when i tried those lat and long with [this online tool](https://www.darrinward.com) it gave me perfect line with pins. `print` log the cooridnates perfectly.

[image: Tested coordinates]
[image: MapSDK polyline]

### Coordinates

```
6.8517432035942099,79.905121140256398
6.8475310038839003,79.902849560677893
6.8581436667655202,79.908119598477995
6.8374054133955697,79.893569033667305
6.8566833715949702,79.907449213862293
6.8406604416732097,79.898999668732202
6.83810886461925,79.892979702055399
6.8542092852358296,79.906306928098104
6.8402581522304899,79.895430151447599
6.8368830112804098,79.894324662238304
6.8440497480396596,79.900090321972897
6.8493188219208703,79.902743613421805
6.8484064936701703,79.902548063620799
6.85723423027141,79.908170560449307
6.8450230546359396,79.899919834062402
6.84973481577528,79.903571158721903
6.8459125422004998,79.899705760255401
6.8551684683252603,79.906455958336494
6.8414650205586502,79.901498481705701
6.8405259121273101,79.899981692507794
6.8513044109631798,79.904290326014106
6.8373792317329203,79.895165984713401
6.8372333821392299,79.895255911941504
6.8466924363811001,79.900271203443296
6.8506548972864199,79.903621031045802
6.8390314607013396,79.892975427284696
6.8469577236164803,79.901166977435295
6.83748895475187,79.895160402688802
6.8398749735270101,79.896293487474196
6.8407466076378203,79.893662072792594
6.8422778556187103,79.900998165905406
6.8398627359483797,79.893336938768499
6.8408240983326403,79.894646443501003
6.8560738395963403,79.906751504242294
6.8469752417941097,79.902100302353404
6.8374541960720299,79.895048104300997
6.8374381558016104,79.895128792781804
6.8524381890956798,79.905752716660402
6.8407501699466602,79.900907306074998
6.8401687173236496,79.897176772430399
6.8405627925012604,79.898056201711199
6.8430614378366998,79.900337923392598
6.8532910058338699,79.906087154597003
```

Comment: can you post your `locationDetails` values?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I updated the question with coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the data array. since im getting the coordinates from coredata those werent in order. so thats why it didnt draw the perfect line one after another. once i sorted the array i got it perfectly.
  `locationDetails = locationDetails.sorted(by: { $0.id < $1.id })`

Answer (score 0):

I have used MKDirection Request for creating a polyline

```
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Handle Error
     }
     else
     {
         //[self showRoute:response];
         for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
         {
             [self.mapView addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
          }
     }
```